# Elastic Beanstalk error implementación

Tags: nodejs, aws

estoy intentando implementar un backend en un AWS ElasticBeanstalk Node.js 12 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.2.3 mas marca un error al parecer en bcrypt y truena el build...

Package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node .",
    "test": "jest",
    "coverage": "npm test -- --coverage",
    "postcoverage": "opn coverage/lcov-report/index.html",
    "dev": "nodemon -i \"*.test.js\" .",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon -i \"*.test.js\" -r dotenv-safe/config .",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "docs": "apidoc -i src -o docs && apidoc-markdown -p docs -o DOCS.md",
    "postdocs": "open-cli docs/index.html"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.14.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/test/setup.js"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "apidoc": "^0.20.0",
    "apidoc-markdown": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "dotenv-safe": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "jest-cli": "^25.1.0",
    "mongodb-memory-server": "^6.3.3",
    "nock": "^12.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "open-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "sinon": "^4.0.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.5.4",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bodymen": "^1.1.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dayjs": "^1.9.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.4",
    "mongoose-keywords": "^0.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-http": "^0.3.0",
    "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "querymen": "^2.1.4",
    "rand-token": "^0.4.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5"
  }
}
```

Console log:
Failed to execute '/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.9.1-linux-x64/bin/node /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.9.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/var/app/staging/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/var/app/staging/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)

full console log:
https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-851540085043.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/environments/logs/tail/e-m62m2tfndy/i-001cc27b5be77394e/TailLogs-1607097192790.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20201204T155314Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIOUOORMVUTXOJUHQ%2F20201204%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=a2e91e25cf5b0abccbd574807fbe41f3d960587a0bc318551ddab2d7ecd23439

Comment: Hola, Andres. Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, traduce la pregunta Y el título a español, que es el idioma oficial

Answer (score 0):

Es muy posible que sea debido a una diferencia entre las versiones de node en tu `package.json` y la que está instalada en el ambiente de ElasticBeanstalk.

Al ver el error aparece que tu EB tiene la versión v12.9.1 de node (`/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.9.1-linux-x64/(...)`) mientras que tu `package.json` especifica la v12.14.0 .

Modifica el engine en tu `package.json` para que quede

```
...
"engines": {
    "node": "12.9.1"
},
...
```

y debería funcionar